# Get the total Author Favorited posts

Tags: php, posts, count, meta-value

I am using the plugin https://favoriteposts.com.

To be a little clearer I have posts on my site that have a favourite count as a meta value. I want to get the total favourite count of all posts belonging to a particular author which the displays on each authors author.php

I have about 300 authors on my site and they would like to see a final count all their posts that have been Favorited on their profile (which is the author.php)
So for example
Post 1 has been Favorited 4 times 
Post 2 has been Favorited 3 times 
Post 3 has been Favorited 6 times 
Total Favorites = 13

I have managed to get it to bring out a list of posts with a favorite value (When a post has never been Favorited the value is empty, when it gets Favorited the value adds 1, when it gets unFavorited it goes to 0.) So I can get it to output any posts with a field value whether its 0,1 or 44 using this code

```
    <?php

$args22 = array(
    'post_type' => array ('menus', 'recipes' ), 
    'author' => get_queried_object_id(),
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'meta_key' => 'simplefavorites_count',
        'value'   => '0',
        'compare' => '>=' 
        )

);


$my_query = new WP_Query( $args22 );?>

Found posts: <?php echo $my_query->found_posts;?>

<?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ):?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> Has been added to <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'simplefavorites_count', true );?> saves</li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();


}?>
```

Ive tried this also Which did not work at all

```
   <?php


global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS favorites_count FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'simplefavorites_count' AND post_author = '1'";
        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $query );


?>
<h2>Post Count: <?php echo $count; ?></h2>
```

I also tried this which also did not work

```
    global $wpdb;
global $post;

$sql = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE
    $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND   $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'simplefavorites_count'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $curauth->ID
    )
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";



// Results can be parsed as OBJECT, OBJECT_K, ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

// See your results printed out (optional)
print_r($result);
```

Can anyone advise please

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't 100%c clear to me. Is this right: You have posts on your site that have a favourite count as a meta value. You want to get the total favourite count of all posts belonging to a particular author?

Comment: Yes that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$args22 = array(
    'post_type'  => array ('menus', 'recipes' ),
    'author'     => get_queried_object_id(),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'meta_key' => 'simplefavorites_count',
        'value'    => '0',
        'compare'  => '>=',
    ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args22 );

echo 'Found posts: ' . $my_query->found_posts . '<br />';

// declare variable and set total votes to 0
$total_fav_count = 0;

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {}
        $my_query->the_post();

        // add custom field value to total votes
        $total_fav_count += get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'simplefavorites_count', true );
    }
}

//
echo 'Total user favorite votes: ' . $total_fav_count . '<br />';

wp_reset_postdata();
```

It's also a good idea to check if `simplefavorites_count` meta key exists:

```
<?php
$args22 = array(
    'post_type' => array ('menus', 'recipes' ), 
    'author' => get_queried_object_id(),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'simplefavorites_count',
            'value'   => '0',
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'simplefavorites_count',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
```